# Is there a way to flag a user as a spammer?

Tags: discussion, flags, spam

I was wondering if it is possible to flag a user as a spammer?

I know you can flag a post as spam. But in the last two days I saw [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4454815/bajotz-x) posting answers like 20 times his name in new lines, (his answer has been deleted already, so I can not link).

I flagged it as spam, and probably others did as well. But it may save time to flag him as a spammer.

Is it possible?

Comment: He definitely needs to be squashed, I agree.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

No, just flag the posts. The account will lose the ability to post anything at all soon enough.

I have seen posts from that account too, and the biggest problem here is that people were using close votes and down votes to handle the content rather than flagging as spam.

Spam flags carry extra penalties and feed back into the automated spam detection system, and given enough posts flagged, even the IP address may end up being blocked.

Comment: The user has been handled....errr... removed...destroyed.

Comment: @bluefeet: thanks. It was [posts like these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27958639/bajotz-wattpad-artwork) that I was referring to; no idea why that post did not gather enough spam flags to be auto-redacted, for example.

Comment: Probably because it was such an inept spam attempt that some people didn't even recognize it.

Comment: @BilltheLizard That's very true, it was reviewed with no action needed on it.

Comment: Well I am glad we won't see any more of his spam.

Comment: @Dzyann Yeah... about that...

Comment: Shouldn't a custom flag be used to tell mods about a pattern of behavior?

Comment: @bluefeet, well one can dream...

Comment: @bluefeet, if the post was reviewed "no action needed", the reviewers may need to be looked into as well.

Comment: @jpmc26: if they're not obvious spammers, yes. If it is obvious spam, just spam-flag all their posts and they'll have a very quick ban.

Comment: @dfeuer that already has been taken care of.